# Cannot Display Image from Nvarbinary[max] database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

How can i display the image while the image in the database is 0xFFD8FFE00.......

Im using MVC 5 and EF

My Code to upload image:

```
        string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                               Server.MapPath("~/Content"), pic);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
             file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
             model.Image = ms.GetBuffer();
        }

        var image = new Image()
        {
            Image1 = model.Image
        };

        db.SaveChanges();
```

As you can see im using viewModel with byte[] data type for Image

How to convert it to image and display it in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert `byte[]` to `based64` string which can be convert to html format like

```
@{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.Image);
    var imgSrc = ($"data:image/png;base64,{base64}");
}
```

this will convert image to `base64string` and i assume `Model.Image` is of type `byte[]` and finally add the `imgSrc` to html tag `image`

```
<img src="@imgSrc" />
```

another way is to use `Viewbag` so in action

```
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Image);
Viewbag.imgSrc = ($"data:image/png;base64,{base64}");
```

and in view use `viewbag`

```
<img src="@Viewbag.imgSrc" />
```